# Cone inside a sphere in the first octant

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates

I have to evaluate the integral
$$\iiint_{W} (x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}dV$$
where $W$ is the region which lies in the first octant inside the sphere
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=16$$
and bounded by the cones
$$z=\pm\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$$

In spherical coordiantes, clearly
$$0\leq\rho\leq4$$
and since it's in the first octant, then
$$0\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{2},\qquad\frac{\pi}{4}\leq\phi\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Therefore, the integral will be
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{4}\rho^{5}\sin(\phi)d\rho d\phi d\theta$$
which value is
$$\frac{512\sqrt{2}\pi}{3}$$
Is it correct?

Comment: I have not evaluated the integral but the set up and bounds are correct.

Comment: As the region is in first octant, it would have been more clear to state that the region is bound between $z = 0$ and $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. If it is in first octant, it cannot be bound by $ ~ - \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ though we can try and infer what is being said. But that is more commentary on the question wherever you picked it up from and not your work.

Comment: @MathLover yes, that's what I thought too.

Comment: I believe the final result is incorrect due to $\sin^2\phi$ integration.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu my mistake, but I did without the power square.

Comment: Yes the final answer is correct. When I saw it earlier, I thought it was $\sin \phi$ but I guess I may have not noticed.